# How can I log out from my account?

Tags: support, logout

I have an account on http://security.stackexchange.com and I am able to post questions but I don't know to log out. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the StackExchange dropdown in the top left hand corner.
2. Click the 'log out' link beside the site you are on

[image: logout button]

3. Confirm!